# Wordpress Multisite phpmyadmin-delete multiple tables with prefix wp_xx_

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Trying to delete multiple wp multisite tables in phpmyadmin

Example Task

delete all tables belonging to site id 73 (currently there are 9 tables) in database istheplaDBbb9h3

i can identify the tables as wp_73_commentmeta, wp_73_comments, etc etc

Entered the code below in the SQL tab of phpmyadmin

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' )
    AS statement FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_schema = 'istheplaDBbb9h3' AND table_name LIKE 'wp_73_%';
```

and clicked Go

the code appears to have been accepted and while the tables appear to be identified nothing happens as no rows (0-0) are deleted

see template image of result at http://i.imgur.com/sjoVP0J.png

Obviously I am omitting something or am in the wrong tab!

Any help at all much appreciated

Comment: look i think i've a solution : just with print view from my initial query I can get a ready made drop statement and that presumably is that!

Answer (score 0):

First things first : make sure your tables are backed up!

You need to write a `DROP TABLE` for every table, i think this should give you a `DROP TABLE` for each table, and one thing you can run once. You are concatting drop table once at the moment, so switch em around and add the separator to run multiple queries at once:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('DROP TABLE ', table_name) SEPARATOR ';') 
AS statement FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'istheplaDBbb9h3' AND table_name LIKE 'wp_73_%';
```

This wont run the query for you: you have to grab the thing that this has produced like you have found out after you asked the question. Also, make sure that it is backed up and the query is right first.